# C++ Any benifits using pointer to vector of pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, unordered-map

Before I start, I have already looked at these questions:

[Memory consumption of a pointer to vector of pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9796600/memory-consumption-of-a-pointer-to-vector-of-pointers)

[Pointer to vector vs vector of pointers vs pointer to vector of pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5648746/pointer-to-vector-vs-vector-of-pointers-vs-pointer-to-vector-of-pointers)

And they both do not answer my question.

---

I am working on a project where it involves millions of instances to work with.

The data structure I am using is a bit complicated to look at for the first time, the structure itself isn't really of any importance for this question.

Now, if I had the following:

```
vector<object*> *myVector;
```

Everything goes to the heap.

However, what happens if I used this:

```
vector<object*> myVector;
```

Does the vector itself get stored on the stack? And its contents are then stored on the heap? For example, if the vector had 10 million instances, would I have 10 million references on the stack for 10 million objects on the heap? Or am I missing something?

Moreover, if I used this:

```
vector<object> *myVector;
```

Where do the contents of the vector go? Does everything go on the heap? If yes, then does it work recursively? For example:

```
vector<vector<vector<int>>> *myVector;
```

Are all the inner vectors then stored on the heap? If yes, then it should be enough deleting `myVector` in the destructor, without worrying on anything else?

Anyway, I am assuming all the answers that apply to `vector` would also apply to `unordered_map`. Please tell me if I am wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Even for `vector<object> myVector` the elements you put into the vector are stored on the free store (heap in your example).

Comment: @GillBates Interesting, so if I used `vector<object> *myVector` everything goes to the heap? I don't want the vector to be stored on the stack because it might have a huge size and I do not want to change the stack size. But I didn't know the objects inside of any vector go on the heap.

Comment: It doesn't matter if your vector is stored on the stack with a huge size. Just because it contains a lot of elements will not make it bigger on the stack, it just has bookkeeping members that are negligible, just keep it there and allocate with `<object>`.

Comment: You could try `sizeof(vector<object>)`, `sizeof(vector<object*>)`, and `sizeof(vector<vector<vector<int>>>)` and see that they all have the same size. And rather small.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, elements of a `std::vector` will **always be dynamically allocated on the heap**. For most implementations, a `std::vector<T> foo`, where `T` could be a pointer or not, there will always be three pointers on the stack that describe the vector itself, but not the elements. For a `std::vector<T> *bar`, there is one pointer, `bar`, on stack. The three vector pointers as well as the vector elements are on the heap.

Similarly, for an `std::unordered_map`, the elements itself will always be dynamically allocated on the heap. Generally, any std type that has a `Allocator` template parameter, or any type that contains a variable amount of data, will have it's data dynamically allocated on the heap.

Now there are special cases, like custom allocators, weird optimizations, specifics of terminology, but for practical purposes, this is what you should know.

The next thing that you might want to learn about, are smart pointers, e.g. `std::unique_ptr`, and `std::shared_ptr`, ownership semantics and RAII. That is actually more important to know in order to write correct code (*What do I need to delete and worry about?*).